# Azure file upload

Tags: file-upload, azure

I'm using the standard file upload control on my site hosted with Azure:

```
<input id="input-file" name="file" type="file" />
```

I'm uploading to: MySite/images/profiles. Whenever I try to upload I get the following error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
'C:\\DWASFiles\\Sites\\MySite\\VirtualDirectory0\\site\\wwwroot\\images\\profiles\\be0d3d56
-307a-4e3b-a78a-50bac885d760.png'.\r\n   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 
errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, 
FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, 
Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, 
Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)\r\n
```

It is interesting to note, that I have two sites on Azure, this works on the first one I set up, but fails on the second one I set up, they both have the same code, one is for production and the other is for testing.

Any ideas? I thought I might have to setup a storage container, but then I don't understand why it works for the production site. There is a storage container created that matches the name of the production site, but I'm not using any special code to target that, I'm targeting: MySite/images/profiles

Comment: Could you share your server side code? it might be possible that one of the server does not have required folder structure or aspnet user does not have access to the desired folder.

Comment: That was it, brilliant. I have an empty site/images/profile, and when I publish to Azure it doesn't create that folder. I added a dummy image to the site/images/profile directory and published, and it works. THANK YOU.